# How does one sets an animation to loop in a ping-pong manner?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For Unity 2022, I'd like to make an animation to ping-pong loop forever but cannot figure it out.

**Thank you to not suggest the following:**

1. Toggle debug mode in the inspector and set legacy mode and wrap mode to ping-pong

   - this does not work for the (not so by now) new animation system
2. Duplicate the first key frame and move it to the end so that it loops
3. Create a script that will set it to ping-pong

   - obviously that does work but it's not really answering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't want to modify the existent animation clip, so you can use 2 states and play them back and forth.

1. Create a sub-state machine "pingpong". This is optional, just to make the state machine look cleaner.
2. Create 2 states "forward" and "backward" in "pingpong" machine.
3. Create transitions between "forward" and "backward" states.
4. Assign the same motion (animation clip) to "forward" and "backward" states.
5. Change the speed property of "backward" state to -1.

Then you can play either "forward" or "backward" state to start the ping-pong animation. You may also adjust the transitions to make better effects.

Comment: Though that does work, there is no preview about that ping pong behavior when creating the animation in the Animation window.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to preview it with the animation window. How about manually dragging the timeline?

Comment: Well, luckily for me I just want to ping pong something with two so adding the extra one isn't that much hassle. Other than that, your answer is spot on as it's the simplest to do for runtime